# TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rows'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use the pivot_table method of a pandas DataFrame;

```
mean_ratings = data.pivot_table('rating', rows='title', cols='gender', aggfunc='mean')
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-cb4d494f2f39> in <module>()
----> 1 mean_ratings = data.pivot_table('rating', rows='title', cols='gender', aggfunc='mean')

TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rows'
```

The above command was taken from the book '[Python for Data Analysis](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do)' by Wes McKinney (the creator of pandas)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The solution for me was to change 'rows=>index' and 'cols=>columns'):

From:

```
mean_ratings = data.pivot_table('rating', rows='title', cols='gender', aggfunc='mean')
```

to:

```
mean_ratings = data.pivot_table('rating', index='title', columns='gender', aggfunc='mean')
```

Comment: It sounds like a bug in the book that I copied the command from.  I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: No, it is not a bug, these are just the old keywords which have been deprecated for a while and now removed. Hence the error you got

Comment: Ah, ok.  Hopefully this stackoverflow post will help other users who encounter the change in API when reading the book.